# Delivery not found in Pick Outbound delivery App

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, s4hana

I am implementing Pick Outbound Delivery App in S/4Hana 1610.
When I press enter after entering the Delivery No.,It say's

`Delivery does not exist`

Although, it is present in Backend System.

[image: Error]

Comment: this seems to backend error, I don't think its anything to do with SAPUI5.

Comment: @SunilBN it gives same error for all the Deliveries.These Deliveries can be manually picked in Backend.So,there is some issue in the App.

Comment: Did you test the service call on its own? Also it would be good if you could add a picture with the details to the ODATA call. (The service called should be LE_SHP_DELIVERY_PICK)

Answer (score 0):

SAP suggested to use `Change Outbound Delivery App` instead.